# python numpy dynamically add elements to the end of a specific row

Tags: python, numpy, append

I want to do the following using numpy:

- create an an array of arrays using numpy where each row contains only one element such as

[[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]]

xx = np.array([np.array([0])] * 10)

- append an element to a specific row such as

[[0],[0,5],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]]

xx[1] = np.append(xx[1],5)

- retrieve an element from a specific row such as

print(x[1,1])

this means that I need a two dimensional array with different row size and the elements are appended dynamically

Comment: That is not the kind of thing NumPy is designed for. Consider using a list of lists.

Comment: Thanks. So I'll get back to using normal lists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 1):

If using a lists inside a list, you can create it like this

```
l = [[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]]
```

And if you want to append something, just use

```
l[1].append(4)
```

You will get:

```
[[0],[0,4],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]]
```

And if you want to access the new element:

```
l[1][1]
```

Which will return:

```
4
```

Comment: Thanks. But when I use l = [[0]]*10 instead of l = [[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]] the second line (l[1].append(4)) adds the value 4 to all generating [[0, 4], [0, 4], [0, 4], [0, 4], [0, 4], [0, 4], [0, 4], [0, 4], [0, 4], [0, 4]]

Comment: @user3631926: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly